# String in routes as params

Tags: node.js, express

I have route in express like this

api/parent/:id/:name

> but if I am calling this API

```
api/parent/19/myName
```

It is working fine but if my name consist "/" eg "alex 21/2"

```
api/parent/19/alex%20%21/2
```

It send 404 status not found

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: You may have to use regular expression in route at the server side. refer - https://www.lunchbadger.com/a-reintroduction-to-express-js-routing/